# Notation for discrete interval

Tags: notation

The interval between to numbers $[a,b]$ includes all the *real* numbers between and include $a$ and $b$. Is there a similar notation for a discrete interval, lets say for $\{a,a+1,a+2,\cdots,b-2, b-1, b\}$?

Comment: How about $S=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}|a \leq n \leq b\}$?

Comment: How about $[a,b] \cap \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Usually $a,\ldots,b$ is OK